# Runtime of concatenating 2 lists in Python

Tags: python, list, concatenation, big-o

If I have 2 Python lists:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

and I say:

```
print(a + b)
```

I get

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

What is Python doing behind the scenes to create this result? What is the Big O runtime of the operations it performs?

p.s. If this has been asked before or is available elsewhere online I couldn't find it

Comment: first a+b is done, which in python means concatenate the two lists. Then the concatenated list is printed. I don't know about the big O runtime of that list concat, but my guess is O(1)

Comment: With all due respect the fact it does a+b then prints the result is blindingly obvious... is it a for loop? a while loop? does it use list comprehension? I want to know the code behind the code and the runtime of that code

Comment: Oh well, you asked what's python doing behind the scenes for a print(a+b), I would edit the question to be more specific if the answer of @Mehrdad Pedramfar isn't specific enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to this [Link](https://bradfieldcs.com/algos/analysis/performance-of-python-types/):

There are two ways to do concatenating: you can use the append method or the concatenation operator `(+)`.

The append method is “amortized” `O(1)O(1)`. In most cases, the memory required to append a new value has already been allocated, which is strictly `O(1)O(1)`. Once the C array underlying the list has been exhausted, it must be expanded in order to accomodate further appends. This periodic expansion process is linear relative to the size of the new array, which seems to contradict our claim that appending is `O(1)O(1)`.

However, the expansion rate is cleverly chosen to be three times the previous size of the array; when we spread the expansion cost over each additional append afforded by this extra space, the cost per append is `O(1)O(1)` on an amortized basis.

On the other hand, concatenation is `O(k)O(k)`, where `kk` is the size of the concatenated list, since `kk` sequential assignment operations must occur.